# Faulty Nvidia gtx 970 (fan issue)

Tags: graphics-card, fan, temperature, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently bought a EVGA Nvidia gtx 970 from scan.co.uk and when I installed it, it had issues. Like when the graphics card temperature hits 60, one fan spins to 100% and another fan does not spin at all. The fan does not slow down from 100% even if the temperature is down. I read other forums and this is a known issue with gtx series and they solved it by returning the card and getting a new one. I also returned the card last week but now they are saying that the card has been tested and there is no fault. I dont know what to do. Please help !!!

Comment: [I know this comment is totally off-topic for SE, but…] How long did you have it before you returned it? UK distance selling regulations allow you to return within 14 days & simply get your money back. You don't even need to specify a reason. They cannot get out of that one, no matter what they try - send them to http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2000/2334/contents/made

Comment: Hi, I had it for 1 week and returned it. But I opened it and tested for a week so can I still get my money back ? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Yes, so long as it is in resale-able condition. It's well worth reading through those regs to know what you have in your armoury after buying anything from the internet in the UK.